# Using USB Drive for Multiple Windows Recovery Disk

Tags: usb-storage

I created a recovery disk of my laptop on a 2TB external hard drive. What I see is the recovery process leaves the un-used space on the external drive as un formatted which is not usable. I was thinking will it be possible if I create partitions on my external drive and use each partition to create recovery disks for more than one machines or use the other partitions for data storage.

Please Suggest

Comment: Windows 10 http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/create-a-system-repair-disc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly partition the remaining space and use it as you see fit. This includes storing recovery images on it. Actually making a bunch of recovery partitions is less clear (depends on exactly how the tool works), but I wouldn't expect it to work. If the recovery partition is intended to be bootable, well, in the usual case there can only be one bootable partition on a drive.

Now, with that said, a Windows recovery disk (if I recall correctly) mostly consists of a .WIM (Windows IMage) file, a program to extract this image and put it on your drive, and some UI to let you know what's going on. The name of this WIM is probably hard-coded, but you could put a lot of WIMs from different computers in their own folders (possibly on a second partition) and use a working computer to swap them as needed.

The other option is to just not use multiple recovery images. An OEM recovery image will contain a lot of stuff specific to that computer model, but you can also use generic Windows recovery images and then store all the drivers, etc. that your different computers need. This would make the recovery less customized to each machine, but would let you get *any* computer (from the right version of Windows) back to a state of at least basic functionality, and (if you have the drivers and other OEM customizations) you could get it all the way back to the way it came from the factory (though it would take longer).

Note that I'm assuming when you say "recovery image", you mean something like what most OEMs include on a semi-hidden partition of the computer's internal drive when you buy a new machine. If you mean a snapshot of a machine that has been modified by user activity - a backup of the operating system state, or something like that - then obviously the generic recovery image isn't what you're looking for (its purpose is restoring you to factory default state).

Comment: @Thanks CBHacking. From recovery image what I mean is all the OEM settings and softwares that came with the machine not just the Windows Recovery. For example when I create a recovery image the tool warns that every thing will be wiped off from the USB drive. But I'll try to create partitions first and then see if the tool can recognize the different partitions and proceeds without formatting the USB drive, In that case I expect something that I want.